# CSS transforms not pixel perfect

Tags: css

I have the following example for an off-canvas menu: http://jsfiddle.net/pwghdvoh/

When you click the button in the top left of the blue header, it moves the main app view to reveal the hidden menu.

[image]

It does this using the following CSS:

```
.showSidebar .app
{
    -webkit-transform:  translateZ(-20px) 
                        translateX(240px);
            transform:  translateZ(-20px)
                        translateX(240px);
}
```

However I'm finding that on various resolutions that the app is not moved 240px to the right and 20px offset from the the top and bottom... If you look at the screenshot, you can see that it's too close to the top and bottom of the screen, it should have 20px at the top and bottom.

Could this be caused by the perspective of the wrapper being incorrect?

I do this dynamically using jQuery:

```
$('.wrapper').css({
    'perspective': $(window).width(),
    '-webkit-perspective': $(window).width()
});
```

So it's always the perspective of the viewport width. But this doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should be looking into translations along the 2D axis, i.e. `translateX` and `translateY`. http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/pwghdvoh/2/ `translateZ` moves your element towards or away from the screen, and depends on the `perspective` value set on the containing parent.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` to the `.wrapper` class, I added position absolute and stretched it to its parent container which is `body` element. and when the side bar is viewed, I gave the `top` and `bottom` properties as `20px` which overrides the already provided `0px` value.

```
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
.wrapper.showSidebar {
    top: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwghdvoh/1/)**